# Display Multiple Balloons conditionally using Windows API - System Tray Icon in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, system-tray, balloon-tip

I wrote a program that can identify outdated software in a Windows System and update them by interacting with the user.

It has a Software Updater Program which displays a System Tray Icon and show Balloon Tips about Available / Downloading Updates and Software installed in the System.

**The problem is It can't show multiple Balloon Tips when each task is processing by it. Such as, when an update is available for a Software, it should remember user showing a balloon like `An update for Software Name is available.` and when user choose to download and minimize it to system tray again, the balloon tip should again show something like `Updates are downloading...Click to view the Progress of Downloads.`**

However I like to know how can I do this by using only one System Tray Icon?

Can I use the `NIM_MODIFY` Flag again and again to change the Balloon Tip according to the current state of the Program?

*I searched about this and I found some examples, but for Visual Studio and C++.*

That's how I tried to show Multiple Tips when the Program is running:

```
unit MainForm-1;

...

const
  NIF_INFO = $10;
  NIF_MESSAGE = 1;
  NIF_ICON = 2;
  NOTIFYICON_VERSION = 3;
  NIF_TIP = 4;
  NIM_SETVERSION = $00000004;
  NIM_SETFOCUS = $00000003;
  NIIF_INFO = $00000001;
  NIIF_WARNING = $00000002;
  NIIF_ERROR = $00000003;

  NIN_BALLOONSHOW = WM_USER + 2;
  NIN_BALLOONHIDE = WM_USER + 3;
  NIN_BALLOONTIMEOUT = WM_USER + 4;
  NIN_BALLOONUSERCLICK = WM_USER + 5;
  NIN_SELECT = WM_USER + 0;
  NINF_KEY = $1;
  NIN_KEYSELECT = NIN_SELECT or NINF_KEY;

  TRAY_CALLBACK = WM_USER + $7258;

  PNewNotifyIconData = ^TNewNotifyIconData;
  TDUMMYUNIONNAME    = record
  case Integer of
       0: (uTimeout: UINT);
       1: (uVersion: UINT);
  end;

  TNewNotifyIconData = record
  cbSize: DWORD;
  Wnd: HWND;
  uID: UINT;
  uFlags: UINT;
  uCallbackMessage: UINT;
  hIcon: HICON;
  szTip: array [0..127] of Char;
  dwState: DWORD; /
  dwStateMask: DWORD; 
  szInfo: array [0..255] of Char; 
  DUMMYUNIONNAME: TDUMMYUNIONNAME;
  szInfoTitle: array [0..63] of Char; 
  dwInfoFlags: DWORD;   
end;

type
  MainForm-1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
private
    IconData: TNewNotifyIconData;
    procedure SysTrayIconMessageHandler(var Msg: TMessage); message TRAY_CALLBACK;
    procedure AddSysTrayIcon;
    procedure ShowBalloonTips;
    procedure DeleteSysTrayIcon;
public
end;

var
  MainForm-1: TForm;

implementation

uses
ShellAPI...,.....,;

procedure MainForm-1.SysTrayIconMessageHandler(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  case Msg.lParam of
  WM_MOUSEMOVE:;
  WM_LBUTTONDOWN:;
  WM_LBUTTONUP:;
  WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:;
  WM_RBUTTONDOWN:;
  WM_RBUTTONUP:;
  WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK:;
  NIN_BALLOONSHOW:;
  NIN_BALLOONHIDE:;
  NIN_BALLOONTIMEOUT:
  NIN_BALLOONUSERCLICK:;
 end;
end;

procedure MainForm-1.AddSysTrayIcon;
begin
  IconData.cbSize := SizeOf(IconData);
  IconData.Wnd := AllocateHWnd(SysTrayIconMessageHandler);
  IconData.uID := 0;
  IconData.uFlags := NIF_ICON or NIF_MESSAGE or NIF_TIP;
  IconData.uCallbackMessage := TRAY_CALLBACK;
  IconData.hIcon := Application.Icon.Handle;
  IconData.szTip := 'Software Updater is running';
  if not Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, @IconData) then
  ShowMessage('System Tray Icon cannot be created.');
end;

procedure MainForm-1.DisplayBalloonTips;
var
  TipInfo, TipTitle: string;
begin
  IconData.cbSize := SizeOf(IconData);
  IconData.uFlags := NIF_INFO;
  if ssHelperState = UpdatesAvailable then TipInfo := 'Updates are available to the programs installed on your Computer' + ' Click to see details.';
  if ssHelperState = UpdatesDownloading then TipInfo := 'Updates are downloading in the background. Click to view the details.';
  strPLCopy(IconData.szInfo, TipInfo, SizeOf(IconData.szInfo) - 1);
  IconData.DUMMYUNIONNAME.uTimeout := 2500;
  if ssHelperState = UpdatesAvailable then TipTitle := 'Updates are Available...';
  if ssHelperState = UpdatesDownloading then TipTitle := 'Downloading the Updates...';
  strPLCopy(IconData.szInfoTitle, TipTitle, SizeOf(IconData.szInfoTitle) - 1);
  IconData.dwInfoFlags := NIIF_INFO; 
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, @IconData);
  {Following code is for testing purpose.}
  IconData.DUMMYUNIONNAME.uVersion := NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
  if not Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, @IconData) then
  ShowMessage('Setting the Version is Failed.');
end;

procedure MainForm-1.DeleteSysTrayIcon;
begin
  DeallocateHWnd(IconData.Wnd);
  if not Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @IconData) then
  ShowMessage('Unable to delete System Tray Icon.');
end;

procedure MainForm-1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddSysTrayIcon;
  ShowBalloonTips;
end;

procedure MainForm-1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeleteSysTrayIcon;
end;
...
end.
```

But, this is failing and I keep getting the same Balloon Tip (First One) again and again when the Program is running.......

I don't know how to use `NIN_BALLOONSHOW` and `NIN_BALLOONHIDE` Flags correctly. So, Thanks in Advance for Your Important Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you declaring everything manually? Delphi 2009 already has declarations for the `Shell_NotifyIcon()` API. They are in the `ShellAPI` unit.  It declares just about everything you are trying to use, except for the `uVersion` field (that was added in Delphi 2010).  You are not using the `guidItem` and `hBalloonIcon` fields, so let's not worry about them here. The `uTimeout` field exists, and since it is wrapped in a union with `uVersion`, the data size does not change, so you can just use `uTimeout` when you want to use `uVersion` (or you can define your own union and type-cast the field, but that is overkill).  You certainly do not need to redeclare the entire API.

You are reusing the same `IconData` variable each time you call `Shell_NotifyIcon()`, which is fine, but you are not clearing the `szTip` and `szInfoTitle` fields if your helper state is not `UpdatesAvailable` or `UpdatesDownloading`, so the tray icon keeps displaying the last tip/balloon you have set.  You need to clear those fields when you don't need tips/balloons anymore.

`NIN_BALLOONSHOW` and `NIN_BALLOONHIDE` are not flags. They are notifications that are sent to your tray icon's registered `HWND`.  To receive the notifications, you need to fill in the `Wnd` and `uCallbackMessage` fields and enable the `NIF_MESSAGE` flag.

Also, you need to handle the [`WM_TASKBARCREATED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179.aspx#Taskbar_Creation_Not) message.  If Explorer gets restarted for any reason (crashes, or is killed by the user), the Taskbar gets re-created, so you have to re-add your tray icon again.

Also, make sure your message handler passes any unhandled window messages to `DefWindowProc()`, or you can lock up the system, or at least your app.

And lastly, Delphi 2009 is a Unicode version of Delphi, but there are some sections of your code that are not handling Unicode correctly.  Specifically, when populating `szTip` and `szInfoTitle` using `StrPLCopy()`, you need to use `Length()` instead of `SizeOf()`.  The copy is expressed in number of characters, not number of bytes.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
unit MainForm1;

interface

uses
  ..., ShellAPI;

type
  eHelperState = (Idle, UpdatesAvailable, UpdatesDownloading);

  MainForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    TaskbarCreatedMsg: UINT;
    IconData: NOTIFYICONDATA;
    IconAdded: Boolean;
    ssHelperState: eHelperState;
    procedure SysTrayIconMessageHandler(var Message: TMessage);
    procedure AddSysTrayIcon;
    procedure ShowBalloonTips;
    procedure DeleteSysTrayIcon;
    procedures SetHelperState(NewState: eHelperState);
    ...
end;

var
  MainForm: TForm;

implementation

const
  TRAY_CALLBACK = WM_USER + $7258;
  {$IF RTLVersion < 21}
  NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4 = 4;
  {$IFEND}

procedure MainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TaskbarCreatedMsg := RegisterWindowMessage('TaskbarCreated');
  IconData.cbSize := SizeOf(IconData);
  IconData.Wnd := AllocateHWnd(SysTrayIconMessageHandler);
  IconData.uID := 1;
  AddSysTrayIcon;
end;

procedure MainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeleteSysTrayIcon;
  DeallocateHWnd(IconData.Wnd);
end;

procedure MainForm.AddSysTrayIcon;
begin
  IconData.uFlags := NIF_ICON or NIF_MESSAGE or NIF_TIP;
  IconData.uCallbackMessage := TRAY_CALLBACK;
  IconData.hIcon := Application.Icon.Handle;
  StrLCopy(IconData.szTip, 'Software Updater is running', Length(IconData.szTip));

  IconAdded := Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, @IconData);
  if not IconAdded then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Unable to add System Tray Icon.');
    Exit;
  end;

  if CheckWin32Version(5, 0) then
  begin
    IconData.{$IF RTLVersion >= 21}uVersion{$ELSE}uTimeout{$IFEND} := NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;
    if not Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, @IconData) then
      ShowMessage('Unable to set version for System Tray Icon.');
  end;
end;

procedure MainForm.DisplayBalloonTips;
var
  Tip, InfoText, InfoTitle: string;
begin
  if not IconAdded then Exit;

  case ssHelperState of
    UpdatesAvailable: begin
      Tip := 'Updates are Available. Click to see details.';
      InfoText := 'Updates are available to the programs installed on your Computer. Click to see details.';
      InfoTitle := 'Updates are Available';
    end;
    UpdatesDownloading: begin
      Tip := 'Downloading Updates. Click to see details.';
      InfoText := 'Updates are downloading in the background. Click to see details.';
      InfoTitle := 'Downloading Updates';
    end;
  else
    Tip := 'Software Updater is running';
  end;

  IconData.uFlags := NIF_TIP or NIF_INFO;
  StrPLCopy(IconData.szTip, Tip, Length(IconData.szTip));
  StrPLCopy(IconData.szInfo, InfoText, Length(IconData.szInfo));
  StrPLCopy(IconData.szInfoTitle, InfoTitle, Length(IconData.szInfoTitle));
  IconData.uTimeout := 2500;
  IconData.dwInfoFlags := NIIF_INFO; 

  if not Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, @IconData) then
    ShowMessage('Unable to update System Tray Icon.')
end;

procedure MainForm.DeleteSysTrayIcon;
begin
  if IconAdded then
  begin
    IconAdded := False;
    if not Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @IconData) then
      ShowMessage('Unable to delete System Tray Icon.');
  end;
end;

procedures MainForm.SetHelperState(NewState: eHelperState);
begin
  if ssHelperState <> NewState then
  begin
    ssHelperState := NewState;
    DisplayBalloonTips;
  end;
end;

procedure MainForm.SysTrayIconMessageHandler(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = TRAY_CALLBACK then
  begin
    case LOWORD(Message.LParam) of
      WM_MOUSEMOVE: begin
        //...
      end;

      WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK,
      NIN_BALLOONUSERCLICK: begin
        // display status window...
      end;

      WM_CONTEXTMENU,
      NIN_KEYSELECT,
      NIN_SELECT: begin
        // display popup menu at coordinates specified by Msg.WParam...
     end;

      NIN_BALLOONSHOW:;
      NIN_BALLOONHIDE:;
      NIN_BALLOONTIMEOUT:;
    end;
  end
  else if (Message.Msg = TaskbarCreatedMsg) and (TaskbarCreatedMsg <> 0) then
  begin
    IconAdded := False;
    AddSysTrayIcon;
    DisplayBalloonTips;
  end
  else begin
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(IconData.Wnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
  end;
end;

...

end.
```

Comment: I know it, but I declared them manually because `DUMMYUNIONNAME` is not declared in `ShellAPI` Version of Windows 7 (this PC) and it is the new structure of `NotifyIconData` as I know, can you show me how to clear `szTip` and other fields ? I also added all other parts of my code now.

Comment: `DUMMYUNIONNAME` is very useful and I added it because it can determine System Tray Icon's Balloons' Display Durations........ :)

Comment: You don't need to redeclare the entire `Shell_NotifyIcon()` API just to use the versioning feature. It is possible to use it in Delphi 2009 even though the `uVersion` field does not exist (it was added in Delphi 2010). I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Thank you , this seems to work with my code. I will try this and notify you soon.

Comment: I added the code properly, but why I'm getting the error `TMessage does not contain a member named 'Message'` ? I added `Messages` to the uses list when I started creating this Project, not Today.......Why that?

Comment: @GTAVLover: it was a typo in my example, I have fixed it.